# Can't ssh into Raspberry Pi via Wifi. No problem with hotspot

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ip, wifi

When i try to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ via ssh I get error.

1. I get the IP from
   `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24`, executed from my laptop

`Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.100`

`Host is up (0.094s latency).`

`MAC Address: MAC (Raspberry Pi Foundation)`

2. Both devices are connected to my wifi.
3. when i run
   `ssh pi@192.168.0.100`
   The response is
   `ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.103 port 22: No route to host`

**note:** I dont have device with IP 192.168.0.103

**note:** the IP from the ssh command and the error response are different

**note:** When the same commands are executed, but this time via hotspot, the ip of the RPi changes and I use the new ip in the ssh and the connection is made without problem

Comment: If the hostname of your Raspberry Pi is, let's say "simon", try `ssh pi@simon.local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting **known_hosts** file in .ssh folder from system which you are trying to ssh.
Try again with correct IP address or you can also use `ssh <username>@raspberrypi.local` replace your username

Edit : New Raspberry Pi OS does not come with default **username** and **password**. It needs to be configured before flashing in ***Raspberry Pi Imager*** itself.